# IOS Random Images

Tags: ios, image, random, uiimageview

I'm trying to have a random image display when the view loads.

I can get an image to display but its not random, it comes up as the position of the %.

For example, this code displays the 4th image all the time.

Here is my code.

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int randomImages = rand() % 4;
    switch (randomImages) {
        case 0:
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
            break;
    }

}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely the version of `rand()` you're using uses the same "seed" every time the app is started.  So you'll get the same sequence of random numbers each time.

Comment: Add `srand (time(NULL));` before doing the `rand()`

Answer (score 1):

```
((arc4random() % 4) + 1)
```

i had the same issue with rand() being predictable. switched to arc4random() and life got better.

**EDIT:**

if you want something nice and streamlined you could replace that entire switch block with just the following:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", ((arc4random() % 4) + 1)]];
```

Comment: What should (arc4random() % 4) replace?

Comment: it should replace rand() % 4... i'm simply saying to swap rand() with arc4random()

Answer (score 0):

Try arc4random_uniform(upper_bound).
It returns a number between 0 and upper_bounds-1

Comment: could you give little guidance on how to implement that?

Comment: `int randomImages = arc4random_uniform(4);` in your case... not too difficult, isn't it? o_O

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I just wish I could answer my own question to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
   int randomImages = random()%4;
```