# iOS Multiple Random Image View

Tags: ios, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I have one image view that randomly generates images when the view loads and I want to add a second image view to the same View Controller. I thought I would be able to dupliacte my code and update the property but it's now working. Here is my code:

.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageViewViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

.m

```c
[super viewDidLoad];

int randomImages = rand() % 4;
switch (randomImages) {
    case 0:
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
        break;
    case 3:
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
        break;
}
```

Comment: what are you asking for?

Comment: More information and code would be usefull. Did you dublicate the property as well, and adapt it to your dublicated code? Or are both imageViews using the same property?

Comment: @jerik I didn't know I could assign both imageViews to the same property. That seems like it would be the easy thing to do, but I'm only able to assign one. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: one UIImageView can hold only one image at a moment. You need to create two UIImageView properties as well as two UIImageView's in Interface Builder, then set their images to whatever you want

Comment: @samfisher I made a UIIMage View that randomly generates images. I want to add a second UIIMage View to the same View Controller that randomly generates the same images. http://bit.ly/15j7nDI

Comment: basicly this should not be a problem. Can you show us more of your code, .h and .m file would be helpful.

Comment: in my .h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679302/ios-random-images

Comment: @BrandonHoulihan Update your question with the code. Do not add it in comments. It's too hard to read.

Comment: @BrandonHoulihan Side note - your code can be one line: `_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", arc4random_uniform(4) + 1]];`.

Comment: ACK maddy. @brandon and please the important part of the .m file as well. The more we have the better can we help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my Xcode 4.6.2.

Integrated the comment from @rmaddy.

#### ViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;

@end
```

#### ViewController.m

```c
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", arc4random_uniform(4) + 1]];
    _imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", arc4random_uniform(4) + 1]];

}

@end
```

Tip: [Using Interface Bilder and Assitant Editor to connect properties](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Establishing_Outlets_and_Actions_using_the_Xcode_Assistant_Editor).
hope that helps.

Comment: @BrandonHoulihan I am not maddy :)

Comment: Sorry, I suck at Stack Overflow =(  Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: BTW - its "rmaddy", not "maddy". Glad I could help in a small way.